# Undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass even though it is not null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have such a controller action:

```
def update_grade
    @id = params[:id]
    @grade = "Grade#{@id}".classify.constantize.find_by_id(params[:grade_id])
    # render :text => @grade.grade1.inspect
    respond_to do |format|
      if @grade.update(:grade1 => 2)
        format.html { redirect_to update_grade_homework_path, notice: 'Homework was successfully updated.' }
      end
    end
end
```

I am getting "Undefined method `update'" error but @grade is perfectly fine object. I verified it by inspecting it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you inspect it?

Comment: with that one, render :text => @grade.grade1.inspect

Comment: What does `@grade.grade1.inspect` output?

Comment: perhaps more of the error message would be helpful.  Are you sure that @grade is the object type you expect?  It looks (from the code) that you might have a huge number of models called `Grade1`, `Grade2` etc.  Is that right?

Comment: And what does does `@grade.inspect` output? Also, try rendering `@grade.class` and tell me what you see.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord::Base doesn't have an *instance* method called `update`. (Well, actually, [it does](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/update), but it's a private method so you shouldn't be able to call it using `@grade.update`). You may be looking for `update_attributes`.

```
@grade.update_attributes(:grade1 => 2)
```

(Note that if you're using Rails 3 you'll need to add the line `attr_accessible :grade1` to your model or the above code will throw a MassAssignmentSecurityError.)

ActiveRecord does have a *class* method called `update`, which you can find in the docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class).

The difference in usage should be clear from this example (say you have a model Grade and you want to set the attribute "foo" to "bar" for the Grade with id 5):

```
# Using the class method "update":
Grade.update(5, foo: "bar")

# Using the instance method "update_attributes"
@grade = Grade.find_by(id: 5) # Or just Grade.find(5)
@grade.update_attributes(foo: "bar")
```

That being said, if the error message really does say "Undefined method `update' for *nil:NilClass*" and `@grade` really doesn't equal `nil`, then that is a bizarre error and I can't think of any reason why it might be occurring. Try changing `update` to `update_attributes` and let me know if that works.